# Why self=[super init] ensure the singleton pattern?

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns, singleton

I read many implementation of singleton pattern in Objective-C, and lots of the code contain such a line in the `init` method:

```
if ((self = [super init])) {
   ...
}
```

And according to this page, which is referred by many questions regarding [super init]: https://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/what-does-it-mean-when-you-assign-super.html

`self = [super init]` "always returns the singleton instead of any subsequent allocation".

But why? The following is my implementation of a shared singleton

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Constructors

+ (VoiceProfileManager*)sharedManager {
    static VoiceProfileManager *sharedManager = nil;
    //Executes a block object once and only once for the lifetime of an application.
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedManager = [[VoiceProfileManager alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedManager;
}

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: @ericl That question has nothing to do with the singleton pattern. I am confused about why that code can ensure "always return the singleton instead of any subsequent allocation".

Comment: @ericl I don't understand why it is a duplicate. Could you explain why? How does that question explain singleton?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I deleted the flag.

Comment: I think you've misread cocoawithlove. That's not what he meant. He's saying that in some cases `[super init]` might return something other than the current `self`, not that `[super init]` implies a Singleton. `self = [super init]` is a standard part of the initialization pattern in ObjC for any object.

Comment: @RobNapier So what's the meaning of if ((self = [super init])) there? That's standard part for any object? Or only for the singleton? If so, why?

Comment: For any object. It just says to assign `self` to the returned value of the superclass's  `init`. `self` is not particularly magical here. It's just a value that is returned by `init`. Get your superclass's, modify it (to set your own properties), and return it. Then your subclass will take that, add its properties, and return it, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the `init` method but the `dispatch_once` function to let you build the singleton instance.

```
static dispatch_once_t once;
dispatch_once(&once, ^{
    // every code here will be executed only once!
});
```

The first line initializes a global static variable called `once`, it has a constant value after `dispatch_once` function execute once.

You could assume that there is a global variable pool for the `once` value, when it executes in the second time, it checks whether the `once` value exists in the pool and skip the block execution if it is.

So why the first line initializes the `once` variable only one time? Check the `static` keyword in C language.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The external page you referenced says `[super init]` (not `self = [super init]` as in your question)  "always returns the singleton instead of any subsequent allocation"

So, [super init] could return a different object.  In that case, "continuing to initialize the returned object if it changes is a mistake"